# Get the Checked box input values using Jquery in CodeIgniter using Mysql

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, codeigniter

I want to display checked checkbox value with input box value when i clicking button in codeigniter. Checked checkbox value has deen displayed correctly using join function. but input values is not showing. In my code, when i clicking button all input text values are displayed. my problem to display only checked checkbox input value using join function.

Controller code:

```
             public function unpaid()
             {
          $basicUrl=$this->config->item("basicUrl");
                     $query=$this->db->query("SELECT aa.id as  id,customer_type_id,start_time,close_time,dd.name as customer_name,bb.name as vehicle_name,cc.name as driver_name,other_expensive,paid_amount,payment_date,payment_mode,payment,tour_file,DATE_FORMAT(aa.created_date, '%d/%m/%Y') as created_date FROM ".$this->tbl." as aa
                            left join vehicle as bb on aa.vehicle_id=bb.id
                            left join driver as cc on aa.driver_id=cc.id
                            left join tbl_customer as dd on aa.customer_id=dd.id
                            order by aa.id desc");
                $result=array();
                if($query->num_rows()){
                $i=1;
              foreach($query->result() as $row){
                    $result_row=array();

                  $result_row[]='<input type="checkbox" name="unpaid_id[]" id="unpaid_id" value="'.$row->id.'" />';
              $result_row[]=$row->created_date;
              $result_row[]=$i;
              $result_row[]=$row->customer_name;
              $result_row[]=$row->payment;
              $result_row[]='<input type="text" name="paid_amount[]" id="paid_amount" value="'.$row->paid_amount.'" />';
              $result_row[]=$row->payment_date;
              $result_row[]='<input type="text" name="payment_mode[]" id="payment_mode" value="'.$row->payment_mode.'" />';
               $result[]=$result_row;
              $i++;

          }
    }
```

My view code:

```
           <input type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="save_value" name="save_value" value="Save" />

           <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {

     $('#save_value').click(function(){
        var favorite = [];
        var favorite1 = [];
        var unpaid_id = [];
        var paid_amount = [];
        var payment_mode = [];

       $.each($("input[ type='checkbox']:checked"), function(){             

            unpaid_id.push($(this).val());

        });
        var unpaid_id = unpaid_id.join(",");

        alert(unpaid_id);

        $.each($("input[ id='paid_amount']"), function(){           
            paid_amount.push($(this).val());
        });
        alert(paid_amount.join(","));
        var paid_amount = paid_amount.join(",");

       });
      </script>
```

Thanks @

Answer (score 0):

use the class in place of id

```
  $.each($("input[class='paid_amount']"), function(){           
        paid_amount.push($(this).val());
    });
```